# How to Optimize Android application with multiple webviews?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

I have an application with a page containing a list of 100 webviews, all loading different webpages. The application gets hanged as I keep scrolling down. Is there a way to optimize this?. Any solutions will be greatfull.

Answer (score 0):

There can be memory leak problem in `WebView`. If you are using `WebView` in your application then you should define it in the xml layout.

Simply define the container in the layout and create a `WebView` at runtime and pass the application context instead of activity here. This is because even your activity destroy webview will keep reference of it and here memory leak!!.

From Android 3.1 to 4.3, Android uses webkit as core of webview in which there is bug where memory leak problem arises much and now Android 4.4 onwards it uses chromium.

Lastly, in your `onDestroy()` release the resources allocated by it.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(webView != null) {
        webView.removeAllViews();
        webView.destroy();
    }
    webView = null;
}
```

Comment: Hi @TGMcians, Thanks for the reply, I am actually having a list view of webviews with html content. After Loading the html content into the list of webviews, the application hangs.

Comment: @user2893317 use pagination instead of loading complete list items.